# How to add a navigation bar to a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uitableview

I added a subview to my application. The view controller is a UITableViewController. When I open the .xib file I see the table, but I can't drag a navigation bar onto it. So once the user enters the view, they have no way of getting back to the previous screen. What can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the UITableView nib representation cannot have it. You can simulate the UI in the case you have a navigationController.

If you want to have a navigation controller, your UITableView has to be pushed into the stack of navigationController.

Assuming your view controller is ViewControllerA has a navigationController, then this method will make sure you have navigation controller in your UITableView:

`[viewControllerA.navigationController pushViewController:tableViewController animated:YES];`